# GitHub Actions Invalid Workflow File Error

Tags: github, elixir, github-actions, elixir-mix

I started using GitHub Actions and I was able to setup a CI pipeline for Elixir, the action builds and tests without any issues. I also wanted to deploy the application using the heroku actions so I went ahead and added the one that is available in GitHub but after doing that I'm getting the following error:

**Invalid Workflow File
Every step must define a uses or run key**

This is how my workflow looked before adding the heroku action:

```
name: Elixir CI

on: push

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    container:
      image: elixir:1.9.1-slim

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: |
        mix local.rebar --force
        mix local.hex --force
        mix deps.get

  test:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      db:
        image: postgres:11
        ports: ['5432:5432']
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1.0.0
      - uses: actions/setup-elixir@v1.0.0
        with:
          otp-version: 22.x
          elixir-version: 1.9.x
      - run: mix deps.get
      - run: mix test
```

And this is how I added the heroku action

```
  deploy:

      runs-on: ubuntu-latest

      steps:
        - uses: actions/heroku@1.0.0
        - name: GitHub Action for Heroku    
        - run: |
            heroku login

          env:
            CI: true
```

[Here](https://github.com/shakenbytes/riot/commit/5de61c7b3cf387ccbaef152a4b930470b485fe08/checks?check_suite_id=310245092) is the error for more details.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You have too many `-` where you are defining the step. There should only be one `-` per step in the job.

The README for [`actions/heroku`](https://github.com/actions/heroku) hasn't been updated yet to show an example for yaml workflows. There is an [open pull request](https://github.com/actions/heroku/pull/6/files#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8) to update it though. The following is the example from that pull request which might help you.

```
on: push
name: Deploy to Heroku
jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: login
      uses: actions/heroku@master
      env:
        HEROKU_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY }}
      with:
        args: container:login
    - name: push
      uses: actions/heroku@master
      env:
        HEROKU_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY }}
      with:
        args: container:push -a calm-fortress-1234 web
    - name: release
      uses: actions/heroku@master
      env:
        HEROKU_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY }}
      with:
        args: container:release -a calm-fortress-1234 web
```

Comment: Apparently only the "uses" lines count as "steps" in the job. Dashes in front of `name` are fine (?!) but only the first `uses` can take a dash.

Comment: And the error message is "sooooooooooo" helpful. I hate yaml, so easy to make a mistake and not know about it until so much later so often.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @peterevans, also check the indentation, it is important:

https://github.community/t/run-failing-invalid-workflow-file/127574